# How to use transparency with supersized jquery plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, background-image, supersized

I just downloaded and tried supersized jquery plugin. It's really cool but I can't seem to set transparency on the background image. I read the documentation on [their site](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) and couldn't find a way to set it.

Is there anyway I can achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would find the supersized.css file and edit #supersized for opacity

```
 #supersized {
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: -999;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 opacity:0.6;
 filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  }
```

If you wanted to make specific opacity for specific slides you could make more specific selectors and alter those to your liking.